# Deceased credit report. Any recommendations?

Tags: credit-report

One day, my wife decided to check her credit report out of curiosity. To her shock, she discovered that one of the major credit bureaus had mistakenly marked her as "deceased." It was a complete surprise, as she was very much alive and well.

Understandably, she was deeply concerned about the potential consequences of being erroneously declared deceased. She realized that she needed to take immediate action to rectify this mistake. Here's how she went about it:

1. Contacting the Credit Bureau: she began by reaching out to the credit bureau responsible for the mistake. She found their customer service number and called them right away. She explained the situation and expressed her concern about the "deceased" status on her credit report.
2. Documenting Her Identity: The credit bureau representative requested various forms of identification from my wife to prove her identity and that she was indeed alive. She gathered her driver's license, social security card, and other relevant documents to send to them.
3. Written Dispute: In addition to the phone call, she submitted a written dispute via email to the credit bureau, outlining the error and attaching copies of her identification documents. She emphasized the urgency of resolving the issue promptly.
4. Follow-Up: she knew that these issues could take time to resolve, so she diligently followed up with the credit bureau every few days to check on the status of her case. She kept records of all her interactions, including the names of the representatives she spoke with and the dates of her communications.
5. Seeking Legal Advice: As a last resort, she consulted with an attorney who specialized in credit and consumer protection laws. The attorney reviewed her case and offered guidance on the legal steps she could take if the credit bureau failed to correct the mistake promptly.

The question is, how much of the correct action was taken? Do you have any additional recommendations on how to proceed in this situation? We would be grateful for any recommendation.

Comment: What has the credit bureau said and how long has it been?  It sounds like the lawyer is saying that the credit bureau still has time to correct the mistake and still be prompt so you probably just want to wait for the process.  But the actual timeline may be different than I'm inferring.

Comment: How much time has passed?  Did the credit agency offer a solution time line?

Comment: And this is one of the reasons to do a periodic check, even if you're sure your credit rating is excellent. Sometimes data entry errors happen

Comment: It's been over 4 weeks now and so I think this process has taken a little longer. The lawyer advised me to create a dispute because the credit bureau reports deceased as explained in this article [https://consumerattorneys.com/article/mistakenly-reported-as-deceased-lawsuit](https://consumerattorneys.com/article/mistakenly-reported-as-deceased-lawsuit). I found this to be a very useful resource but decided to seek advice on a legal forum. Is it worth getting into a dispute involving the court to prove my case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry to hear about your wife's situation; that must have been a stressful and unexpected ordeal. From what you've described, it seems like she took the right steps to address the issue of being mistakenly marked as "deceased" by the credit bureau.

Make sure to check all three major credit reports (Equifax, Experian, and TransUnion). Errors may not be present on all three reports, so it's essential to address any discrepancies on each one.

Comment: There is actually at least one more small credit report agency, but they're probably not worth bothering with.